# How to choose which ObservableCollection to bind to a listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, observablecollection

Is that even possible? I have two ObservableCollections. I want to bind and populate a listbox with one of them. For example let's say that we have 2 buttons - one for Twitter and one for Facebook. Clicking on a Facebook button it will populate listbox with friend's names from facebook observable collection  and it will bind it. Clicking on Twitter it will populate listbox with Twitter followers and populate listbox and bind it.

How to choose which collection will be populated in listbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use one observable collection and fill based on the users choice. You could also fill it with the names from both sources and have a filter to filter out one or the other (apparently you need a wrapper object where you can indicate whether the name is a facebook friend or twitter follower).

**Edit**: Here is some quick code example of how you can do it:

```
public interface ISocialContact
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class FacebookContact : ISocialContact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FacebookPage { get; set; }
}

public class TwitterContact : ISocialContact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TwitterAccount { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your data context:

```
public ObservableCollection<ISocialContact> Contacts { get; set; }

...

Contacts = new ObservableCollection<ISocialContact> {
                    new FacebookContact { Name = "Face", FacebookPage = "book" },
                    new TwitterContact { Name = "Twit", TwitterAccount = "ter" } 
           };
```

And in your xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FacebookContact}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FacebookPage}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TwitterContact}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TwitterAccount}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
</Grid>
```

This will apply the appropriate template to each object in your collection. So you can have collection with just facebook contacts or just twitter contacts or mixed.

Also note: You do not need the common interface. It will also work if you just make your `ObservableCollection` of type `object`. But given that they are being displayed by the same app in the same list box indicates that you can find some kind of common base and either can create a comon interface or base class.

Comment: But types in Observable Collections are different. I'm new to this so I'm sorry if I'am wrong. Twitter collection is collection of Twitter object and Facebook of Facebook object. Each class has needed properties. @ChrisWue

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I was looking for :) And just one more thing - I have an idea of master-detail with content controler - i need to bind now content control so how to bind that now? Do i bind it just against my interface? @ChrisWue

Comment: I need to use ContentTemplateSelector and program it myself?

Comment: @Flipper: Not 100% sure what exactly you mean, but I you define a `ContentControl` then you can bind it to the `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox`. If you move the data templates into the `ContentControl.Resources` you should be able to do the same thing again as for the `ListBox` (defining several templates depending on the exact type of the object)

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel, create a property that exposes one or the other ObservableCollection, and swap it out when the button is clicked:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _twitterFriendList;
private ObservableCollection<string> _facebookFriendList;

private ObservableCollection<string> _selectedFriendList;
public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedFriendList
{
    get { return _selectedFriendList; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _selectedFriendList)
        {
            _selectedFriendList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedFriendList");
        }
    }
}    

void TwitterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    SelectedFriendList = _twitterFriendList;
} 

void FacebookButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    SelectedFriendList = _facebookFriendList;
}
```

Then in your XAML you can just bind to the property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedFriendList}"/>
```

Comment: I'm using Observable Collection like this: private ObservableCollection<TwitterUserProfile> _twitterUser; In TwitterUserProfile. Objects in obeservable collections are different types. TwitterUserProfile has all properties that i need. Facebook has different properties. I'm new to wpf and binding and all that.

Comment: If the two collections contain data of different types, then your best option for showing them in the same `ListBox` is to unify them somehow.  For example, create a common interface that both the Twitter and Facebook objects can implement, and bind against that interface.

Comment: Here's a [tutorial on interfaces](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Interfaces.aspx) that explains the concept in some detail.

Answer (score 0):

A non-elegant way of accomplishing this is to put 2 listboxes in the same location and bind 1 to the twitter collection and the other to the facebook collection. Bind their visibility to a property that changes based upon the button clicks. Personally, I'd have 2 radio buttons and display the listbox based upon which one is selected.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TwitterCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTwitterItem}" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsTwitterSelected, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}" />
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FacebookCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFacebookItem}" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsFacebookSelected, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}" /> 

<RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" GroupName="rdoOptions" Content="{Binding Path=TwitterLabel}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsTwitterSelected}" />
<RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" GroupName="rdoOptions" Content="{Binding Path=FacebookLabel}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsFacebookSelected}" />
```